# multiquoted string in .rc2 file, VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I was building a VC++ project and i happened to have data some thing like inside Resources.rc2 file

"My data contains "multiple quoted string" and also symbols like "<" ">" "\""

It seems Quotes and <, >, and \ are needed to be escaped.

I'm getting error RC2104 upon compiling with RC.exe in VS08. It terminates the string on first occurance of a quote. What can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about your RC file, try:

[Resource Compiler Error RC2104](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2z28y0f(VS.71).aspx)